# WPF : Keeping default style when inheriting from ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem, multipleselection

Hey Guys (and girls if any :)

I needed a different list box selection policy than the one provided by default with WPF listboxes, i.e. beeing able to have an extended selection withou any modifier key.

No problem on that, here is what I did :

```
class EnhancedCcyPairListBox : ListBox
{

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new CcyPairListBoxItem();
    }

}

internal class CcyPairListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
{
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsSelected = !IsSelected;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I can't tell if it's the best way to do, but it seems to work exactly as I expected.

Except that... by doing so, I have lost the defaults ListBoxItem style I had before. How can I tell to my derived classes to keep their default style ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this above the EnhancedCcyPairListBox declaration

```
    [StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(CcyPairListBoxItem))]
```

Edit

Add this to the static constructor of CcyPairListBoxItem"

```
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(CcyPairListBoxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CcyPairListBoxItem)));
```

and in Themes/Generic.xaml add

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CcyPairListBoxItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not works. And it does not seems to be surprising to me because, after all, this line of code just tell the listbox to use the style of the CcyPairListBoxItem, which is precisely where the real problem stands.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work : I can't get the base ListBoxItem Style. That seems crazy that each time you inherit from an existing WPF control it should be such a mess to just retreive the basic control style O_o. I'll continue to investigate...

Comment: @Bruno The last comment indicates that this didn't solve your issue, but you've marked it as the answer. Did it actually fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because the WPF context of our application is quite special, I wanted to be sure that it was not an issue that was very specific.

So I took the above two classes and imported them in a brand new WPF test project. I created a Themes directory that registered a Resource dictionnary in which I put the Style as NVM mentionned earlier.

[image: Project structure]

Content of Generic.xaml :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/InheritedListBoxStyling;component/Themes/Styles/TempDic.xaml" />
    <!-- Reference here the Resource dictionnary used for your own component -->
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Content of TempDic.xaml :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:InheritedListBoxStyling="clr-namespace:InheritedListBoxStyling">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type InheritedListBoxStyling:CcyPairListBoxItem}"        
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Content of Window1.xaml.cs

```
namespace InheritedListBoxStyling
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                source.Add("toto " + i);
            }

            l1.ItemsSource = source;
            l2.ItemsSource = source;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> source = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}
```

Content of Window1.xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="InheritedListBoxStyling.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:InheritedListBoxStyling="clr-namespace:InheritedListBoxStyling" 
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

        <ListBox x:Name="l1" SelectionMode="Extended" 
             Margin="0,0,12,12"  Height="100" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
             VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="120" />
        <InheritedListBoxStyling:EnhancedCcyPairListBox 
            x:Name="l2" SelectionMode="Extended" 
            Height="100" Margin="12,12,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here the result  :

[image: Sample App]

=> the default styling is not applied and, as in my "real case" issue, the only kind of styling that seems to be applied is the gray selected item style.

Any idea about what's going on or what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What makes you think that the default style is not applied? I see two list boxes with the same style. (Selected item becomes gray when list box loses focus...that is expected behavior)

Comment: No, event when the goog listbox is selected, the slected item is displayed in gray. But anyway, I in this case the problem seems to be caused by the e.Handled =true in the overriding of the previewMouse button event. Removing this line of code results in a correct item styling. So your answer was the good one, and I have to find another way to acheive the desired behavior. I mark this question as resolved

Comment: Aaaah I just assumed you would have put a break point to check that control reaches the previewmousedown handler!! BTW I have a heavily customised list box with custom selection policy and I should advise that there are many fringe cases to consider when overriding selection policies. There is no one line fix to anything related to selection.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm discovering right now. Anyway, thanks for your answers ;)

Comment: @Bruno This is useful additional information, but shouldn't be added as an answer, since it just adds more information to the original question. Can you edit your question, adding everything from this answer, then delete it?